# capturing touch on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, touch

I've tried using the `PageViewerViewController` in order to pass through few pages in `scrollMode`. Like another question here in `SO` (I can't seem to find it tough) I want to capture the touch. so on `viewDidLoad` I searched through the `Views` in that controller and found the `scrollView` and just added a `TapGestureRecognizer` and it didn't work that well so I added `self` as its `delegate` and told him to work simultaneously with other `GestureRecognizers` and than it worked fine. The thing is, when I try to click on a `UIButton` on one of the pages, it doesn't recognize the click. and when I set the work simultaneously to off, it suddenly works fine.
What am I doing wrong?
**More Info:** I think I went all over the web with the following problem, and tried to write the code from scratch, tried to change the code, and adding another `TapGestureRecognizer` so far has the best outcomes.

I'm currently out of any ideas. Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

**For more clarification**, I'm trying to captrue all touchStarted, touchMoved, touchEnded on `UIPageViewerViewController` in ScrollMode. I tried adding another `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the inner `UIScrollView`, to the superview of `UIScrollView`, to `self.view` of which the `UIPageViewerViewController` is added on. and when I remove the working simultanously my UITapGestureRecognizer stops working randomly. When I set the working simultanously to work, I'm not able to click any `UIButton` until I start another UIViewController. and then for some reason, it does work.

**Edit** I'm only using 3 pages, is `UIScrollView` better?

**I changed everything to just a UIScrollView, when I remove the UITapGesureRecognizer, everything works fine, I receive touches, and everything runs smoothly.**

Is there any other way than UITapGestureRecognizer added to UIScrollView to capture touch?

Answer (score 1):

Your button doesn't recognize clicks because the tapGestureRecognizer intercepts them. You can set more complicated area where tapGestureRecognizer has major priority. Try to add this code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer == yourTapGestureRecognizer) {
        return !CGRectContainsPoint(yourButton.frame, [gestureRecognizer locationInView:yourScrollView]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing that function but for some reason gestureRecognizerShouldBegin isn't fired

Comment: What's the target of yout tapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: some function that never got called so I just left it empty. I did all the work on touchesBegin till touchesEnded when I subclassed that UITapGestureRecognizer

Comment: I asked about the target but not the selector. The target must me your class (basically UIViewController) where your selector is called.

Comment: sorry, the target is `self`. which is a subclass of `UIViewController`. and shouldReceiveSimul... does gets fired

Comment: Then you should disable working simalteniously and try to add gestureRecognizer to scrollView's superview. Because scrollView has it's own gestureRecognizers and they prevent working of your custom gestureRecognizers.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I do get the button clicked, but since I disabled working simalteniously, from run to run touchFinished not getting called

Comment: I tried moving the touchRecognizer to self.view, to scrollView.superview. nothing seems to work..

Comment: I think you should update your question by adding the most significant parts of your code. Now I'm confused of what exactly you use :)

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you are looking for a UIView would be better than a UIScrollView.  If you want to get all the touch events anyway then you can just implement your own scrollview functionality.  You can do the paging in `onTouchEnded:` by UIView animations setting the UIView's origin to some value based on where the touch ended.  It's a bit of work, but it would likely be easier than trying to send touch events to two places when Apple wants to consume them in the ScrollView.

Comment: Subclassing UiScrollview and implementing the same functions won't work?